# Expandable List View Group Position variable causes index out of bounds

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

The error points to the the line `String groceryName = recipeNames.get(parentPosition);` I understand what the error means, but I don't fully understand what is causing it. Oddly enough it only really happens when some of the groups are expanded. When I push the delete button, it's not deleting the correct item, meaning it's reading the wrong index. If all of the groups are collapsed it deletes just fine. Any help is much appreciated.

```
package groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableIngredientListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private List<String> recipeNames; // header titles
private HashMap<String, List<String>> recipeIngredients;
private Button mDeleteButton;

public ExpandableIngredientListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.recipeNames = listDataHeader;
    this.recipeIngredients = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this.recipeIngredients.get(this.recipeNames.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Changed from groupPosition to groupPosition - 1
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_view_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_recipe_ingredient_item);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.recipeIngredients.get(this.recipeNames.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.recipeNames.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.recipeNames.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_view_group, null);

        mDeleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_recipe_from_grocery_list_button);
        //TODO: Add a dialog to ensure user wants to delete the recipe
        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int parentPosition = groupPosition;
                //This is where the error is
                String groceryName = recipeNames.get(parentPosition);
                RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(parent.getContext());
                recipeNames.remove(parentPosition);
                recipeIngredients.remove(parentPosition);
                dbHelper.deleteGrocery(groceryName);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_recipe_header);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);



    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Edit: This is the logcat error I'm getting.

```
02-17 23:55:19.558 11403-11403/groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist, PID: 11403
                                                                                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
                                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                     at groceryproject.jacob.com.recipelist.ExpandableIngredientListAdapter$1.onClick(ExpandableIngredientListAdapter.java:98)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: add your error log

Comment: share logcat/error

Comment: Added the logcat error. I'm not sure that it's going to do anything, but I'm going to rewrite the constructor so that I can pull directly from the database instead of passing info as a parameter. I I also want to remove the need for a hashmap with arraylist by accessing my custom object directly. I know this isn't going to fix anything, but it will make it a little easier for me to track down where it's breaking. I'll update with progress.

Answer (score 0):

So I seemed to have finally found a solution. For whatever reason, deleting the line:

```
if (convertView == null){
```

from both the getGroupView and getChildView fixed it. I'm not sure if deleting it from getChildView actually did anything, but I did it for good measure. I have no idea why this was a fix, but it hasn't crashed yet in my attempts to replicate the issue.